# Pygtk and embedding an offline google earth using python

Tags: python, pygtk, google-earth

I would like to start designing a linux application that has an embedded window displaying position information in google earth .

I recognize that having an offline limited region of google earth isn't a straight  forward task, but i'd like to get some recommendations on how to start with this.

There is something called Google Map engine , but what API is associated it with it...some directions would be helpful

Comment: Maybe a [Static Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/) could help ?

Comment: @Alexander , unfortunately , Maps don't show spatial data...i need google eath because, i need to simulate 3d paths